# Interpretation of a mixed effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

I have the next dataset:

```
 structure(list(TOTAL = c(8, 17, 23, 26, 8, 13, NA, 16, 8, 
 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 13, 7, 2, 28, 41, 56, 60, 60, NA, 0, 47, 47, 
 64, 6, 4, 3, 12, 0, 0, 0, 6, 44, 54, 53, NA), sex = structure(c(2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
 t = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
 4L), levels = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), id = c("pat144", 
 "pat144", "pat144", "pat144", "pat17", "pat17", "pat17", 
 "pat17", "pat207", "pat207", "pat207", "pat207", "pat277", 
 "pat277", "pat277", "pat277", "pat339", "pat339", "pat339", 
 "pat339", "pat387", "pat387", "pat387", "pat387", "pat483", 
 "pat483", "pat483", "pat483", "pat586", "pat586", "pat586", 
 "pat586", "pat6", "pat6", "pat6", "pat6", "pat964", "pat964", 
 "pat964", "pat964")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = "data.frame")
```

This dataset represents repeated measurements TOTAL, in four-time points.
The variable id, identifies every person in the sample (everyone appears 4 times).
sex is the variable sex, and the variable t is basically represents the when the measure was taken.  If I plot the data. I have a plot like this:

```
   xyplot(TOTAL ~ t|sex,data=sample_data,group=id,type="b")
```

This plot basically show the trajectory of the TOTAL values over time t.

[image]

Then I am estimating a mixed effects model, using this:

```
    mod.0 <- lmer(TOTAL ~ t + sex + (1 | id),
          data = sample_data)

    summary(mod.0)

Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: TOTAL ~ t + sex + (1 | id)
   Data: sample_data

REML criterion at convergence: 272.2

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-3.05893 -0.40536 -0.00919  0.48353  1.62346 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id       (Intercept) 433.3    20.82   
 Residual             101.6    10.08   
Number of obs: 37, groups:  id, 10

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)    7.594      9.178   0.827
t2             6.000      4.508   1.331
t3             9.993      4.670   2.140
t4            16.802      4.864   3.455
sex2          15.265     13.862   1.101

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr) t2     t3     t4    
t2   -0.246                     
t3   -0.231  0.483              
t4   -0.231  0.463  0.442       
sex2 -0.604  0.000 -0.010  0.006
```

Then, I am considering the fitted values of this model:

```
xyplot(fitted(mod.0) ~ t | sex,groups=id, data =
         sample_data, type = c("b", "g"))
```

(I have a question regarding this plot, why is appearing one green point alone with a line joining it with other point??)

[image]

THen I have considered then population level predictions:

```
pop.level.predictions <- predict(mod.0, re.form = ~0)
xyplot(pop.level.predictions ~ t | sex, group=idpat,data =sample_data, type = c("b", "g"))
```

Note that in the previous plot, I have some questions:

1. why  there are in t1a and t2 3 points, but in the t3 and t4 4 points??
2. I cant give an interpretation of this plot, what does it represents? Why I dont have only one line as in the tutorial that I am seeing?

[image]

I am interested in apply a repeated measures approach, given that I have a measure in different time points, I am testing it based on the next tutorial:

https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/math/statistics/sfs/Education/Advanced%20Studies%20in%20Applied%20Statistics/course-material-1921/Regression/MixedModels_Lab.pdf

Thanks in advance for your help.-

Answer (score 3):

There are three missing `TOTAL`s in your dataset. The model is fitted on the 37 complete observations.

`lmer` reports this fact in the `summary` output.

```r
Number of obs: 37, groups:  id, 10
```

So the `fitted()` and `predict()` functions return 37 numbers, not 40. `xyplot()` does its best to align the inputs with the outputs but doesn't quite manage it since there are 40 inputs but only 37 outputs.

You can avoid the confusion by dropping rows with missing values before you start the analysis.

```r
nrow(sample_data)
#> [1] 40

sample_data <- na.omit(sample_data)

nrow(sample_data)
#> [1] 37

mod.0 <- lmer(
  TOTAL ~ t + sex + (1 | id),
  data = sample_data
)

xyplot(
  fitted(mod.0) ~ t | sex,
  groups = id,
  data = sample_data,
  type = c("b", "g")
)
```

[image]

To plot population level predictions, I suggest you construct a complete grid of `t`✕`sex` values. It helps to keep track of the predictions.

```r
grid_data <- data.frame(
  t = factor(rep(1:4, times = 2)),
  sex = factor(rep(1:2, each = 4))
)
grid_data
#>   t sex
#> 1 1   1
#> 2 2   1
#> 3 3   1
#> 4 4   1
#> 5 1   2
#> 6 2   2
#> 7 3   2
#> 8 4   2

pop.level.predictions <- predict(mod.0, newdata = grid_data, re.form = ~0)

xyplot(
  pop.level.predictions ~ t | sex,
  data = grid_data,
  type = c("b", "g")
)
```

[image]